# Oracle synonym for remote package / procedure

Tags: oracle, package, synonym

we have a package/procedure in a remote database.   Say PACKAGE_1.PROCEDURE_1.   We want to create a synonym in the local database, that will allow us to still call the package.procedure without coding a DB link in the call.  So, to the caller, it looks as though the package.procedure is local to that database.

Can this be done using a synonym?

Answer (score 0):

Sure, you'd just create the synonym

```
create [public] synonym package_name 
   for schema_name.package_name@db_link;
```

Then you'd just call

```
package_name.procedure_name
```

in your code and wouldn't need to reference the database link.